# Колонки id не найдено в этом ResultSet’’е.] with root cause

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

Не понимаю, в чём проблема.

Мой код:

```java
public List<StudentHomework> getHomework(Long id) {
    //language=sql
    String sql = """
            SELECT persons.last_name, persons.first_name, subjects.subject_name, class.title, homeworks.content
            FROM students
                     JOIN persons ON students.person_id = persons.id
                     JOIN class ON class.id = students.class_id
                     JOIN teachers ON class.teacher_id = teachers.id
                     JOIN homeworks ON teachers.id = homeworks.teacher_id
                     JOIN subjects ON homeworks.subject_id = subjects.id
            WHERE students.id = ?
            """;
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new StudentHomeworkMapper(), id);
}
```

Класс в который я всё сохраняю:

```java
package com.example.school.dto;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StudentHomework {
    private Long id;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String subjectName;
    private String clazz;
    private String homework;
}
```

Mapper:

```java
package com.example.school.mapper;

import com.example.school.dto.StudentHomework;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class StudentHomeworkMapper implements RowMapper<StudentHomework> {
    @Override
    public StudentHomework mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        StudentHomework studentHomework = new StudentHomework();
        studentHomework.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
        studentHomework.setLastName(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
        studentHomework.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
        studentHomework.setSubjectName(resultSet.getString("subject_name"));
        studentHomework.setClazz(resultSet.getString("title"));
        studentHomework.setHomework(resultSet.getString("content"));
        return studentHomework;
    }
}
```

Сообщение об ошибке:

```
2022-05-04 15:37:58.887 ERROR 10100 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT persons.last_name, persons.first_name, subjects.subject_name, class.title, homeworks.content
FROM students
         JOIN persons ON students.person_id = persons.id
         JOIN class ON class.id = students.class_id
         JOIN teachers ON class.teacher_id = teachers.id
         JOIN homeworks ON teachers.id = homeworks.teacher_id
         JOIN subjects ON homeworks.subject_id = subjects.id
WHERE students.id = ?
]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Колонки id не найдено в этом ResultSet’’е.] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Колонки id не найдено в этом ResultSet’’е.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:2946) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2829) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at com.example.school.mapper.StudentHomeworkMapper.mapRow(StudentHomeworkMapper.java:13) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.school.mapper.StudentHomeworkMapper.mapRow(StudentHomeworkMapper.java:9) ~[main/:na]
```

Comment: У вас в Select отсутствует id. Вам нужно в запросе добавить вывод id

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос текстом вместо скриншотов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а он разве должен быть обязательно?

Comment: Если вы читаете поле (а вы читаете его в мапере), то нужно его включить в запрос.